# Converting bespoke formatting into html formatting using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have some data where formatting commands have been created in the format

```
^B Makes the rest of the line bold
^I Makes the rest of the line italic
```

etc., and I'm trying to turn this in to html `<b>`, `<i>` etc.

These codes can be combined and occur anywhere in the line, but apply to the rest of the line only.

I've tokenised the data into lines, and am using `analyze-string` on each line to pick up the formmatting marks. The problem is that I need to open the formatting instruction where I find it in the string, but then close it at the end of the string, and what I have doesn't work, as it opens and closes the format where the marker is, as you would expect:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\^([BIU])">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:element name="{lower-case(regex-group(1))}"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

What I get from this is:

```
<b></b> Makes the rest of the line bold
<i></i> Makes the rest of the line italic
```

where what I want is obviously

```
<b> Makes the rest of the line bold </b>
<i> Makes the rest of the line italic </i>
```

I can't see an obvous way of using `analyze-string` to achieve this, and the only way I can see of doing it is to use a recursive function to process do substring-afters etc., which seems rather messy.

Anyone with a better idea? Thanks!

Screwtape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need add another pattern to your regex expression to capture the rest of the line after the symbol, which can then be output inside your newly created element

Try this

```
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\^([BIU])(.*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:element name="{lower-case(regex-group(1))}">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: That's a great starting point - it works except when there is more than one format, but I can call that recursively which is much nicer than trying recursive substring afters. (I should have included an example with more than one format code - sorry!)

Comment: Sorted - moved the analyse-string into a called template and called recursively to manage the case where you have "^B^I". Thanks very much!